# AJAX issues with CiviCRM 4.7

Tags: 4.7

We seem to be having intermittent AJAX issues with our 4.7 installation.  I've seen the following post:

https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35850.0

And done a bit of troubleshooting. I can see from the console that I'm receiving a 500 error from Apache, however, when I look in the logs, there's no additional information beyond the 500 and an empty message. I've got every piece of debugging I know of turned on - does anybody have ideas about how to get additional information about the problem?

In case it helps, the specific call that is failing is when trying to edit the navigation menu. Most of the other AJAX calls seem to be working fine. I can manage ACLs, etc. Is it possible that I've missed a permission somewhere that is causing this to fail? I'm logged in as an administrator trying to make this change.

Answer (score 1):

For our specific implementation, we ran into an issue with a permissions module we had previously written. We're still not entirely sure what the conflict was, but disabling the module enabled us to edit the navigation menu again.